# Ideal place for checking quote and change it

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, event-observer, quote

After the user adds a product to the cart, I need to run a check on the quote because I have to manipulate the total price if necessary and then save the changed quote.

Where is the ideal place to make my quote check?

Maybe in the controller Magento_Checkout/Controller/Index/Index ?

Comment: You can use observer for that "checkout_cart_product_add_after" this event can be used to manipulate the prices

Comment: @Anuraag, hmm, maybe `checkout_cart_save_before` is better? Or maybe `custom_quote_process`...